# Need to use variables values of one JSP in another

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP named size.jsp which gives the size of a drive of a PC. This is on a Linux PC named A. I don't have access to machine but can run the jsp on my machine. The values of 4 variables is printed in the browser out as below.

The output of size.jsp is below

```
total_vault_size =2.0T
used_vault_size =1.7T
available_vault_size =144G
used_percent =93%
```

I have another JSP includeSize.jsp on windows machine B. I want to use the values of size.jsp output in includeSize.jsp to club the output of both machines A,B.

If i run only includeSize.jsp in browser is there way that it can fetch the values of size.jsp in the background and use it in includeSize.jsp.

Comment: Are you saying that both machines have different web applications with size.jsp in one server and includeSize.jsp in another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Connect to remote machine, and download the file.
2. Parse the file.

Example implementation:

```
URL url = new URL("http://machineA/path/to/size.jsp");
InputStream in = url.openStream();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");

Properties prop = new Properties();
try {
    prop.load(reader);
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
System.out.println( prop.getProperty("total_vault_size"));
```

Comment: that's a possible solution but is the file size.jsp going to be accessible remotely ?

Comment: From the OP's text parts: `I ... can run the jsp on my machine` and `is there way that it can fetch the values of size.jsp in the background` I'm guessing that it will.

Comment: That's a good solution. I hope he asks for the same and JSP is accessible.

Comment: From the vague information given by the OP your solution is probably the closest you can get to a concise solution

Comment: I can access size.jsp from machine B browser but I don't have access to machine A where size.jsp is hosted on.

Comment: @ManinderSingh Yes, that's how I understood your question, and this solution should work, if run on machine B.

Comment: Thanks Max   for you prompt help.